# Вырезать регуляркой число В js

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть массив из картинок, как можно из определенного элемента вырезать число?

```
var regV = /\d{1,3}/;
atrib2 = array[razdacha2[1]];
var result2 = atrib2.match(regV)
```

Comment: Нет. 
Выборку делать не с ХТМЛ документа. 
у меня имеется массив картинок array[]

Comment: .getAttribute('src') не работает
Там походу вообще атрибута src нет

Comment: Вот массив с этими значениями
[[img#63 images/рубашка.jpg], [img#61 images/рубашка.jpg], [img#113 images/рубашка.jpg], [img#112 images/рубашка.jpg]]

Как можно вырезать отсюда цифру 63 допустим

Answer (score 1):

```
var im = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); // массив картинок 
var n = im[1].src.match(/\d+/)[0]; // из адреса берем число
```

Вы это имели в виду?